# How to get return value from stub function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, grpc

Using grpc, i create a stub 'client'.
He has an 'auth' method.
I call like that

```
client.auth({uuid:cookies.uuid}, function(err, r){} );
```

The function in the parameter will be called asynchronously, but I need to get its value synchronously.
How can this be done?

Comment: Have you tried making it an `async` function and using the `await` keyword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an asynchronous operation. You can't make it complete synchronously. You could use a library like [grpc-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grpc-promise) or [grpc-caller](https://bojand.github.io/grpc-caller/) to get a promise, and then use `await` to be able to code in a similar style to synchronous code.

Answer (score 2):

Is impossible to convert an asynchronous method to a synchronous one. You can "simulate" it vanilla with `async/await` and promises, without any external package.

```
function clientLogin() {
    return new Promise((accept, reject) => {
        client.auth({uuid:cookies.uuid}, (err, r){
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                accept(r);
            }
        });
    });
}

// This code needs to run inside and async function
try {
    let r = await clientLogin();
    console.log(r);
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}
```

`clientLogin()` returns a `Promise` that will be resolved *later in the future* (AKA asynchronous). With the `await` keyword you can tell JavaScript to wait for the `Promise` to resolve before continuing with the execution, so is a simulated synchronous code, although is not really syncrhonous.

If you are not used to `async/await`, is a bit long to explain, so better look for a tutorial.